# NULL assigned to mysql_fetch_array output?

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to do the SHA1 of a variable, I'm using this snip of code:

```
$prow=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT SHA1($password) AS SHA"));
var_dump($prow);
```

However, I'm always getting prow to be assigned as null, why is it?

Comment: You need a `FROM tablename`

Comment: And your password consists of digits only, so that you do not have to mark it up as a string value for MySQL …?

Comment: You should not write this kind of all-in-one-line statement – it makes debugging harder (and we can see from your question that you have totally failed at debugging here).

Comment: i would separate those pieces out into a diff statement for each function just to see what is failing...

Comment: @Fred-ii-: He's not selecting from a table.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Are there exceptions to the `select` rule?

Comment: @Fred-ii-: It's not a "rule".  You only need a `FROM` if you are selecting from a table.  `SELECT SHA1('ABC') as SHA` is a valid query.  You are just working with literals, and not field names.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I'm going to look into that, thanks.

Comment: Chances are `$password` is a string, and doesn't have quotes around it.  Try `mysql_query("SELECT SHA1('$password') AS SHA")`.  P.S. Do not use the database just for string processing.  Also *NEVER* assume your query succeeded.  *ALWAYS* check `mysql_error()`.  `$sql = mysql_query(...);  if(!$sql){ die(mysql_error()); } $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);`.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Check this out: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/22796

Comment: @RocketHazmat Thanks, I learned something more today.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Learn something new everyday :-)

Comment: @RocketHazmat For sure and what I'm learning now and built code with success, has come from SO / Google and a slight Zest from myself. Plus after reading what you wrote about the possible problem (string), makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: I try to make sense.  I don't always :D

Comment: notice how everyone's going crazy over this question and the OP hasn't even commented once...?

Comment: @RocketHazmat You made sense today, and that matters. `+1` on [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19385687/null-assigned-to-mysql-fetch-array-output?noredirect=1#comment28730888_19385687) ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me....

```
$password = 123; 
$query    = "SELECT SHA1($password) AS SHA"; 
$result   = mysql_query($query); 
$prow     = mysql_fetch_array($result);

print "<pre>";
print_r($prow);
print "</pre>";
```

and returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 40bd001563085fc35165329ea1ff5c5ecbdbbeef
    [SHA] => 40bd001563085fc35165329ea1ff5c5ecbdbbeef
)
```

try testing your database connection...?

**edit** -- use [mysql_ping()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-ping.php) to test your connection.  if it returns false, that's your issue....

**edit -- you need quotes around the string**... i can't believe i missed that.

```
$query = "SELECT SHA1('$password') AS SHA";
```

Comment: What if `$password` is a string, and not a number?

Comment: oh!  then it fails for `mysql_fetch_array` because `$result` is not a valid resource.  good job!

Comment: Why does the return value twices the result in number and tag based indexes?

Comment: if you look at the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php?wb48617274=BCA3943F) for that function ($results->fetch_array()), it takes an optional parameter that says what the return format is... `MYSQLI_ASSOC, MYSQLI_NUM, or MYSQLI_BOTH` (and those are PHP constants).  By default, it returns `MYSQLI_BOTH` which is both the associative array and numerically indexed array... so if you want just an associative array just call it like `$results->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)`.

Comment: OH! I did that comment for the `mysqli_` function but I am going to leave that there because it's the same idea.  This is [documentation for mysql_fetch_array](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) and it would look like this if you wanted just the associative array returned:  `mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC);`  They are slowly removing the deprecated `mysql_` functions so you should try to use/learn the`mysqli_` or `pdo` classes.

Answer (score 1):

Null is returned when an error occurs. Your call to `mysql_query()` is probably returning false.

If that's all you're doing with the database, why not use PHP's own `sha1()` function:

```
$sha1 = sha1($password);
```

(N.B. you should be using `bcrypt` or `scrypt` to hash passwords properly - SHA1 isn't adequate.)